# COM object can't be created when I upgrade client .Net Framework version

Tags: .net, com, instantiation

I have .net console application and com object I want to instantiate via:

```
var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("myProgID");
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

everything works fine when client platform is .net framework 3.5, but crashes when I upgrade version number to 4.0 with

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxx-xxx} failed due to the following error: 80004005 (E_FAIL)?

COM object is built with .Net Framework 3.5

What shall I do to make my Com object usable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit version of Windows? And it works again when you switch back to .NET 3.5?

Comment: No. It's Windows XP on 32-bit platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was - Avira Antivirus !

Another problem with Antivirus is described here:
[(SEH)Exception initializing Nlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400130/sehexception-initializing-nlog)

I deinstalled that and found out that everything became ok !

Answer (score 1):

The error message is hopeless, you'll need to debug the COM server to see what is going wrong.  If you don't have the source code for it then you may get something out of the trace you get from SysInternals' ProcMon.  Realistically, you need help from the component vendor or author.

Comment: Thank you, @Hans, I'm the vendor - what shall I check?

Comment: Start with your COM class constructor, class factory if you have one.  Check if your QI implementation is hit with odd IIDs.

Comment: Class Factory implementation is hidden for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the GUID changed. Are you sure that it's looking for the correct GUID, and that the COM object is registered with that GUID?

Comment: All I do - change client application .net framework version. GUID stays the same.